# Construction of Co-expression network of Microarray data usin R language

Tags: r

I have to construct a Biological Co-expression network of genes of my Microarray data (contains expression of around 16000 genes)using R language.

The link to the tutorial that I am following is https://github.com/iscb-dc-rsg/2016-summer-workshop/tree/master/3B-Hughitt-RNASeq-Coex-Network-Analysis/tutorial.

I am getting an error message at the step of Data Preparation

> Error in heatmap.2(cor(raw_counts), RowSideColors = cond_colors, trace = "none",  :    'RowSideColors' must be a character vector of length nrow(x)..

Please help.

[Screenshot of the Workspace in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuU4L.png)

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you are following requires at least two gene data batches so that each condition will have at least two entries in 'sample_metadata.csv' file in the tutorial.